# Chrome extension to download multiple files via background page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension Popup receive input from user intermittently during the session, popup sends the user data to background page and gets stored there(keeps on appending), when user closes the particular webpage, data in background is dumped as text file in local machine.

when user open the same webpage in same session, new user data stored in the background was unable to download, as in the background, chrome blocks the download "This site is attempting to download multiple files, do you want to allow". This situation is bcoz, the background page remains un-refreshed for the second download attempt, which is equal to downloading multiple times.

how to force download the file ? Is there a way to mention an exemption for download from background page for multiple times or

Is there any way to refresh background html page after each download by background.

Thanks !